# Rails: Refresh page on ActiveRecord change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to implement a website that has a "newsfeed" of sorts. I want to be able to refresh the page every time an entry is added to a specific model. Is there any way to do this? I don't want to refresh the page every 5 seconds, but rather only refresh when a change is made.

Comment: You should look into loading the page asynchronously – there's probably something built into RailsJS that can help facilitate this.

Answer (score 0):

you should use js for periodically ask update.
Or fashion way - [rails4 with websockets](http://ngauthier.com/2013/03/websockets-in-rails-4.html)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could take a look at Rails 4 Streaming. There is a couple of links about this subject:

http://blog.remarkablelabs.com/2012/12/live-streaming-rails-4-countdown-to-2013

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#streaming-and-file-downloads

http://tenderlovemaking.com/2012/07/30/is-it-live.html

Or take a look how to perform push notifications using [faye](http://railscasts.com/episodes/260-messaging-with-faye) or [socket.io](http://socket.io/).

Answer (score 0):

Check this sexy project out called [sync](https://github.com/chrismccord/sync). I think it's exactly what you're looking for.